# How to assign elevation values to contours derived from a raster elevation file

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour

I extracted contours from a raster elevation file (SRTM). The contour layer does not contain elevation values. How can I use qgis to assign elevation values to the contour layer?  Is there a better way to obtain contours with elevation values?

I performed the following steps to extract the contours:
Raster - Extraction - Contour

Additional information:
Windows operating system
WGS84 projection
Raster filetype: .tif
Resolution: 1 arc-second

Comment: The extracted contours contain no properties at all?

Comment: Only an ID, but iant's answer solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you check the `attribute name` box when converting the raster or the attributes will not be attached (as the note says).

[image]